# Convert and merge pdfs with Aspose

Tags: node.js, pdf, aspose

I am trying to build a service to convert documents to pdfs and merge them using Aspose. So far I haven't found the right combination of functions to do so. Here is the closes I have gotten.

Creating an Aspose document in their cloud:

```
storageApi.PutCreate('file.jpg', null, null, '/tmp/file.pdf', cb);
```

Converting the document to pdf:

```
pdfApi.PutCreateDocument('file.pdf', 'file.jpg', null, 'jpg', null, null, cb)
```

I think this step may be wrong because the pdf is exactly the same size as the jpg. That being said I still get a 200 response.

Merging the documents:

```
pdfApi.PutMergeDocuments('output.pdf', null, null, ['file.pdf', ...], cb)
```

This seems to not be returning the error:

```
{ Message: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' }
```

And then to retrieve the file :

```
storageApi.getDownload('output.pdf', null, null, cb)
```

This is obviously a little irrelevant considering the last step fails, but I think it should work if I can get things going.

What I suspect is happening is the converting step is just renaming the file and not converting it. I've tried with `pdfApi.PutConvertDocument` but I haven't got that working either.

I haven't found the documentation particularly helpful in this area. What steps should I take to get this working?

Comment: Related question by the same person: [Converting documents to pdf and merging using nodejs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37405839/converting-documents-to-pdf-and-merging-using-nodejs)

Comment: @jfriend00 I see you have mentioned this on the other post as well. Is there a so rule against posting similar questions? I could understand this would be bad if one question was a redundancy of the other, but in this case one question is asking about the pros and cons of various  techniques while this question as asking about about a specific implementation of one of those techniques. I think answers to both of these questions could be useful, so I'm interested why you posted these comments. Should I take one down? Thanks.

Comment: I would have flagged one as a duplicate of the other if I thought they were duplicates.  They aren't so they are probably OK.  But, the content is related so a discussion in one may be relevant to people trying to answer the other.  That's why I referenced them to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not passing the list of source documents correctly. Please check http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfcloud/Merge+Multiple+PDF+Files for more details on how to format the list of documents when passing it to **PutMergeDocuments**. Specially focus on the following variable which is passed as parameter in the above mentioned example.

```
var mergeDocumentsBody = {
        'List' : [mergefilename1, mergefilename2]
};
```

I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.